# Use a ClassModule Property to add an Array key

Tags: class, vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a ClassModule that includes the private property `m_Invalid() as String`.

What I need is 2x properties, one to allow public access to get the whole array, and one to allow private access to add a key to the array.

I have come up with this, but if I try and use AddInvalid (`Me.AddInvalid ("Test")`I get a compile error -

> Invalid user of property

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Thanks,

```
Public Property Get Invalid() As String()
    Invalid = m_Invalid
End Property
Public Property Let AddInvalid(ByVal Value As String)

    Dim ArrayLength As Integer
    ArrayLength = UBound(m_Invalid)

    ReDim Preserve m_Invalid(ArrayLength)

    m_Invalid(ArrayLength) = Value

End Property
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does `AddInvalid` need to be a property? Just change it to a Sub (or Function) and it will work, but the name cannot be the same as an existing property:

```
Public Sub AddItem(psTest As String)

    Dim ArrayLength As Integer
    ArrayLength = UBound(m_invalid)

    ReDim Preserve m_invalid(ArrayLength)

    m_invalid(ArrayLength) = psTest

End Sub
```

Also, your code does not do what you think it does. From what I can see, all it does is ReDim it to the same size it already is and then overwrite the last value...? Add one to the ReDim statement to make the array grow:

```
    ReDim Preserve m_invalid(ArrayLength + 1)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks I had missed the +1. And adding it as a method did indeed work.